# Get artifact information through VSTS API

Tags: api, azure-devops, release

In the [VSTS API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#getreleasedetails) there's information on how to make GET requests, but I can't find anywhere in the release API information on the artifact that was attached. I'm using Postman to submit requests, but there is no data returned on artifacts anywhere in the response. How do I find it?

Artifact is attached:
[image: Artifact attached]

Can't show full logs of the request, but the GET URI is https://xxxx.vsrm.visualstudio.com/xxxx/xxxx/_apis/Release/releases?api-version=4.0-preview.4&definitionId=76 and this returns a lot of information, but none on the artifact. Running a similar call but with /build/builds/artifacts returns information on the artifacts, but I can't access the information through the release API for some reason.

Edit: I found information on the artifact by adding the release ID to the URL.

Comment: What information you'd like to get for the artifact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get artifacts by GET a release REST API, you can follow below steps:

1. Use the request

   ```
   GET https://account.vsrm.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseID}
   ```
2. Authorization with basic Auth

   You can use PAT or Alternate credential for the basic auth.
3. Send request and get the artifact url through output

   Make sure the return status is **`200 OK`**. Select Body -> Pretty -> JSON for the output. Search `artifactSourceVersionUrl` in the output, the value for `id` is the url to get the artifacts. such as the url is `https://account.visualstudio.com/_permalink/_build/index?collectionId=fc52d179-f3fd-460b-adb1-5ac84bd0e765&projectId=f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4&buildId=1402` as below example.

   [image]
4. Open the URL and get the artifacts

   The URL is the related build page, in the Artifacts Tab, you can download or explore the artifacts.

   [image]

Comment: I don't have the artifact URL. I'm authenticating with my PAT. The artifact is attached (verified through VSTS) and the GET is returning the right value with a 200 code.

Comment: Is the Version.ID field populated? That should be the BuildId that you can use to get the artifact

Comment: If you can't find the URL, that's mainly caused the release definition is not link a build artifacts. Please check in your release definition and confirm whether there has build artifacts linked.

Comment: @DenverDev: I can get the artifact through the build side, but I can't find it in releases.



Marina: Yes, there is an artifact attached.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots showing the artifact on the release job as well as the response XML from GET https://account.vsrm.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseID}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at the [Get Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-build-artifacts) section of the API? This will provide the name of the artifact as well as the download URL for that artifact as well:

GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts

Is there specific information that you are looking for that is not returned in this call?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in releases or just builds?